# Timeout During SharePoint Gradual Upgrade

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to upgrade a system from SharePoint 2003 to 2007 using gradual upgrade. I've moved all of the smaller site collections successfully, but I'm running into trouble with the larger ones (2-30GB).

The upgrade process is running for a couple of hours and then timing out during DropFullTextSearch. The timeout period seems to be about 30 minutes.

Is there anything I can do to either improve performance for the upgrade process or extend the timeout?

I already tried doing a database migration, but with that method none of the site collections showed up in SharePoint central admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little time with reflector revealed that the upgrade code was calling sp_fulltext_database - searching for that gave me a number of posts about querys running for days and suggestions to reinstall windows.

After restarting the search service, the operation completed in 3 seconds.

Of course this just got me as far as the next timeout (on the DocVersions table) - I have detailed the issues and solution on my blog:

http://www.tqcblog.com/archive/2009/06/05/gradual-upgrade-large-databases-and-timeouts.aspx

Comment: LOL, yeah that could always work!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any more info on the timeout message and where it is coming from (e.g. SQL or SharePoint)? If SQL Server then you could try reorganizing the database indexes and compacting it first.

It is also possible there is some database corruption which [stsadm -o databaserepair](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288636.aspx) might fix.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the error occurred on the temporary database created during the migration process, which limits the preparation options a bit.